.xlsx file corrupt after download from POST API, but working fine in Postman
I have implemented an POST API for downloading some file from the browser, triggering which leads to download the file in my local system from the server through flask API.
Now when opening the file, I am getting two message in Microsoft Excel.


Now the same API when using through postman application works well.
In postman I entered the same api endpoint with my headers and payload, and trigger the api by clicking on Send and Download option in the postman. Now when the file is downloaded, and opened it works well.
So this make to proof that the API from BE is perfect and fine.There might be some problem with my FE Implementation.
here is the code.
const handleDownload = async (datasetName) => {
    const key = "updatable";
    try {
      messageApi.open({
        key,
        type: "loading",
        content: `Exporting '${datasetName}' in progress...`,
        duration: 0,
      });
  
      const parameters = {
        database: "datastore",
        preview_name: datasetName,
      };
  
      // Fetch file as a blob
      const response = await callFlaskPostAPI(postApis.Download, parameters, {
        responseType: "blob", // This ensures we are handling binary data as a Blob
      });
  
      if (response && response.data) {
        // Double-check if data size looks reasonable
        console.log("Downloaded file size:", response.data.size);
  
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        });
  
        // Debug: Check blob properties to confirm binary integrity
        console.log("Blob created with type:", blob.type);
  
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `${datasetName}.xlsx`);
  
        messageApi.open({
          key,
          type: "success",
          content: "File downloaded successfully",
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error("No data received from the server");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      messageApi.open({
        key,
        type: "error",
        content: "Oops, something went wrong",
      });
      console.error("Error downloading file:", error);
    }
  };


Try opening it in one of the Excel clones - they are often more forgiving of format errors. Also since you trust the source what happens if you say "yes" recover the file? Comparing the recovered repaired file against the failing one might be informative. .XLSX' files are disguised .ZIP` files so you can look inside them if you choose to do so.

You're not checking response.ok or response.status, so most likely it's some kind of error response. Check the file size and/or try opening it in a text editor, chances are you'll find it's an HTML 401 error page or something. (Edit: assuming callFlaskPostAPI is like the fetch API and doesn't throw on error statuses. You haven't included the code for callFlaskPostAPI so no idea what that's doing )

This issues has been solved. After getting the file in response, Converted it in utf-8 encoding, and boooom. It worked. The files are now not getting corrupt.
